# Render text to an opengl texture in a standalone program

Tags: opengl, textures

I'm using opengl+glut and wondering if there is a library out there that can render text to a buffer in a format consistent with opengl textures.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? Do you mean that it renders lines of text in a pixel format you can upload to OpenGL with glTexSubImage2D? Do you mean that it renders lines of text to an OpenGL buffer object, which you can then render with array rendering?

Comment: Good question. I wish I knew the answer :) I'll try FTGL as suggested below, but keep glTexSubImage2D in mind.

Comment: How can you *not* have the answer? You're the person who wants something. How can anyone be expected to answer you if you yourself don't know what you're looking for?

Comment: It's actually quite easy. I know I'm going to need a texture to render text into, but for now, since I'm just trying to learn more about opengl I don't care how that's done. Once I get a better handle on opengl, I'll look into my options (which might be platform specific). So, for now, something akin to a stub is all I want.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [FTGL](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ftgl/index.php?title=Main_Page). It uses FreeType to render text to textures, and can also create polygons  if you feel like it. The [tutorial](http://ftgl.sourceforge.net/docs/html/ftgl-tutorial.html) shows the basic usage nicely.